How to prevent a corrupted file to be copied from a computer to a NAS, overwriting the "OK" version?
Here is a scenario I would try to prevent:

Today is 11 Nov 2024. Everything is fine with my Mac's SSD (I hope...). I make a backup from Mac to a NAS.
Time goes on...
Now "today" is 1 Jun 2025. I make a new backup from Mac to a NAS. But what I wasn't aware of is that the same file on Mac has been corrupted because of degradation since yet, and now the corrupted version from Mac's SSD has overwritten the "OK" version on a NAS. The "OK" version is lost and now I have two copies of a corrupted version.



— https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation

Is it possible to prevent such a scenario? What the workflow should be?

Mirroring files is no backup.

This is the sort of thing that Time Machine provides (some) protection against...

@MikeB I never used Time Machine before, and if this Time Machine's feature is not very discoverable and/or requires some not very obviuos steps to use, it would be great to have a dedicated answer.

@jsx97  This is pretty basic for any proper backup software - there are limits but essentially Time Machine will save a new copy if and only if it sees a change to the file.

The "Related" list strikes again, finding an exact duplicate from 13 years ago: https://superuser.com/q/308358/29943

Disappointed - I read NAS as NASA.


The system also isn't aware that the data is corrupted. Unfortunately, Apple's APFS doesn't keep data checksums (your NAS probably uses ZFS or Btrfs, which do). So you need to maintain those on your own – find a tool that would generate sha1sum or xxhash for all photos into a file; configure it to work incrementally (i.e. generate hashes for new files, but never re-generate them for "known" files); then verify those hashes before backup, and generate new hashes wherever you import photos.

If the NAS uses ZFS, then it should run periodic 'scrub' which would automatically notice corruption (and may even automatically repair it, if it's set up as a RAID1 or RAIDZ array). In that case, it might be a good idea to use the NAS as the primary storage for such data (as a separate thing from the "backups" folder), and only keep a secondary copy on the laptop.


Don't use "copy & paste the whole folder once a quarter" as your backup system. There exist various "deduplicating" backup systems (e.g. Borg, Restic) which work in a similar way to Git, keeping many snapshots over time where identical data is only stored once. (Apple's Time Machine is similar but I don't think it quite meets the requirements.)
As the deduplication in such tools is based on hashes of data stored, not on file names, it also means non-identical data (e.g. suddenly corrupted files) will be stored separately and will never overwrite a previously stored different version, meaning that you don't need to compromise on backup frequency – e.g. even if you run the backup job every day, having those old snapshots still gives you several weeks or months to re-run the aforementioned manual sha1/hash checks and notice the corruption.

(Though most likely the program will just skip backing up the corrupted file, as random bit rot doesn't actually change its 'modification time'.)




Supplemental to the accepted answer, btrfs and ZFS allow one to make snapshots of the filesystem. The filesystem is copy-on-write so if you can avoid re-writing unchanged data, the extra space consumed by keeping a large number of snapshots going back in time is acceptably small. (Btrfs and ZFS also have de-duplicating abilities which I haven't  investigated.)
I use btrfs for my archive and rsync -a --delete --inplace --stats to copy across the current state to the archive (after taking a snapshot).
Borg backup is better for an archive that is going to be stored off-site, because all data is encrypted before being written (and de-duplicated and optionally compressed). It does, however, require very significant CPU time if the data is measured in Terabytes, whereas a btrfs filesystem just needs enough space for all the snapshots, and the normal filesystem overheads.

Borg 1.x and Restic keep a cache of file metadata, allowing them to completely skip files that don't look like they have changed since last backup (usually by mtime/ctime), so the cost of backing up large amounts of data only needs to be borne once. (Much less sure about the upcoming Borg 2.x from what I've seen, but hopefully it also ends up having something similar.) As long as the storage is reasonably trusted, I'd just disable the data encryption in backup software – e.g. for my own use, encrypting the whole disk via LUKS is more convenient.

Encrypting a whole disk adds decrypt overhead to all file accesses, not just to backing it up. Obviously, this is necessary if you are concerned about the physical disk being stolen but it gains you nothing against unauthorized access to the system on which it is mounted.
